# php shell_exec WMIC remote computer on the network

Tags: php, shell-exec, wmic

i'm trying to get information about remote pc on the network , like serial number , computer model etc..
and i try the  following commend on php ,but it's not work.

please help

Note : when i use it on CMD and it's work fine  ,also when i test the local ip address on the same code it's work fine

```html
<?php 
$pcname = "test-pc";
$test=shell_exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\WMIC.exe /NODE:". $pcname." COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME");
?>
```

also the i try the following code as well

```html
$test=shell_exec("WMIC /NODE:". $pcname." COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME");
```

Comment: i think that the issue is shell_exec not returning the output of your command. try executing it with exec("$command",$output,$return_code); then do var_dump($output); and var_dump($return_code);

Comment: thanks for reply but still the same issue , when i try on local ip address it's work fine but when i try another computer ip address on the network nothing shown ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution , when you want to exec WMIC on php to get information about remote pc you have to mention domain username and password ,as you can see below ,

```html
$test1=shell_exec('wmic /USER:"domain\username1"  /PASSWORD:"password1"  /NODE:"test-pc"   COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME');
echo $test1;
```